# Why is System.Data.OleDb code contacting Microsoft?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, oledbconnection

I noticed on my PC this week that an OleDBConnection to a LOCAL Access database was taking 2-4 seconds to close (depending on whether or not it is the first call to .Close() or a subsequent one).  Last week this was much faster.

KB2952664 was installed on my machine over the weekend.

The following code triggers an HTTPS tunnel to odc.officeapps.live.com:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim str As String

    str = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\temp\Northwind.accdb;"

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff tt"))
    conn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(str)

    conn.Open()
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff tt"))
    conn.Close()
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff tt"))

End Sub
```

HOW DO I PREVENT .NET FROM CONTACTING MS WHILE IT IS RUNNING???

Here is a Fiddler screenshot showing the URL it is accessing. (left out our Domain Name)  I didn't see any data that it is sending to that URL.

[image: Fiddler screenshot]

Comment: Well, first, you need to **accurately** identify what is causing it to be slow. Is it your server? Can you say with 100% confidence it is due to the Windows Update?

Comment: not 100% sure it was the Windows Update that caused this, but that is my guess since it should be the only thing that changed over the weekend.  This is accessing a LOCAL Access database on my c: drive.  No server involved.

Comment: Oh, wow. That's interesting..Is there a chance there are resources you aren't cleaning up? Did you add any code between then and now?

Comment: check out the sample code I added above.  The .Open() takes about 1 sec and the .Close is taking 2 seconds.  We call .Close after every query in our app, so 2 seconds is just too long.

Comment: If you use HTTPS interception, what is being sent to that server?

Comment: no noticeable data but see Fiddler screenshot above

Comment: Does uninstalling KB2952664 eliminate that network traffic?

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking "Allow Office to connect to the Internet" in Access Options stops this from happening.

[image]

This isn't ideal, because what if I want Office to connect to the internet for other reasons?  Would like to have granular control over this.